# Select parent node based on attribute of current child node

Tags: xml, xpath

There are a number of questions on selecting a parent node based on the value of a child attribute, but none of them seem to address this scenario.

I have some XML:

```
<TABDISP>
  <HEADER ORDER="1" PROMPT="Next of kin" />
  <HEADER ORDER="2" PROMPT="Emergency contact" />
  <ROW ORDER="1" PROMPT="Family name">
    <FIELD ORDER="1" TYPE="TEXT" NAME="NKSurname" MANDATORY="N" />
    <FIELD ORDER="2" TYPE="TEXT" NAME="ECSurname" MANDATORY="N" />
  </ROW>
  <ROW ORDER="2" PROMPT="Forenames">
    <FIELD ORDER="1" TYPE="TEXT" NAME="NKForename" MANDATORY="N" />
    <FIELD ORDER="2" TYPE="TEXT" NAME="ECForename" MANDATORY="N" />
  </ROW>
</TABDISP>
```

From the context of any FIELD node, I want to select the HEADER node where the @ORDER attribute matches (ultimately, I'm extracting the prompt that goes with the field).

I have tried `../../HEADER[@ORDER=./@ORDER]` (which I didn't expect to work, but it needed trying), `../../HEADER[@ORDER=self::node()/@ORDER]`, and am currently wondering if there's an appropriate axis I can use and I've so far failed to find an appropriate function that returns the original FIELD context node that I can put in the filter.

What have I missed?

Comment: So you already have the FIELD node with a specific ORDER, and you need to find the corresponding HEADER node?

Comment: That's correct. I'm trying to do this in a single expression without having to read the value out in one expression and construct a second with the previously saved value (for context, I'm doing this in SQL Server with it's XML tools, so not possibly to split it into two statements).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had cause to revisit this recently, and the answer is in two parts:

1. It's not possible with XPath 1.0. This is fully answered in a different question on this site: [XPath equivalent to current()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42032599/130352)
2. The answer above doesn't help for SQL Server XML, however with further experimentation the same can be performed in SQL Server with something like this:

---

```
declare @t xml = '<TABDISP>
  <HEADER ORDER="1" PROMPT="Next of kin" />
  <HEADER ORDER="2" PROMPT="Emergency contact" />
  <ROW ORDER="1" PROMPT="Family name">
    <FIELD ORDER="1" TYPE="TEXT" NAME="NKSurname" MANDATORY="N" />
    <FIELD ORDER="2" TYPE="TEXT" NAME="ECSurname" MANDATORY="N" />
  </ROW>
  <ROW ORDER="2" PROMPT="Forenames">
    <FIELD ORDER="1" TYPE="TEXT" NAME="NKForename" MANDATORY="N" />
    <FIELD ORDER="2" TYPE="TEXT" NAME="ECForename" MANDATORY="N" />
  </ROW>
</TABDISP>';

select field.xmlnode.value('(./@NAME)[1]', 'nvarchar(20)'), 
        field.xmlnode.value('(./@ORDER)[1]', 'int'), 
        header.xmlnode.value('(./@PROMPT)[1]', 'nvarchar(50)'),
        header.xmlnode.value('(./@ORDER)[1]', 'int')
    from @t.nodes('//FIELD') field(xmlnode)
        cross apply @t.nodes('//HEADER') header(xmlnode)
    where field.xmlnode.value('(./@ORDER)[1]', 'int') = header.xmlnode.value('(./@ORDER)[1]', 'int')
```